# how to swap the row in Jquery Pl Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement like I need to swap rows in Jquery Pl upload plugin. How to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UI Widget](http://plupload.com/example_jquery_ui.php) has an option **`sortable`** - set it to true and you will be able to drag and drop file entries.